# Single-iteration over hierarchy in Java 8

Tags: java, javafx, collections, iterator, hierarchy

How can I implement single-loop iteration over a hierarchy of different objects?

*(I have used for-loops but these represent a different areas of a grid -- I can barely follow all the values used for positioning. Using a single loop would drastically simplify things.)*

This hierarchy of objects is what I have....

```
class Hierarchical < PT extends Hierarchical<?,?,?>,T,CT extends Hierarchical< ?, ?, ? >>{
    ObservableList< Hierarchical > children;  //Zero or more objects..
}

class Seed   extends Hierarchical { /* never has children-objects */ }
class Tree   extends Hierarchical { ... }
class Planet extends Hierarchical { ... }
```

**Edit**: Children in the Planet instance are Trees, same for Trees containing Seeds.

...and this is what I want to do:

```
Planet p = new Planet(); //trees/seeds are instantiated internally.
Iterator< ? > itr = p.getChildren().iterator();
while ( itr.hasNext() ) {
    Object obj = itr.next();
    if ( obj instanceof Planet ){ /* cast to Planet & do stuff */ }
    if ( obj instanceof Tree   ){ /* cast to Tree   & do stuff */ }
    if ( obj instanceof Seed   ){ /* cast to Seed   & do stuff */ }
}
```

Clearly the answer lies in `Iterator< ? > itr = p.getChildren().iterator();`
 but how can it be implemented? It would seem that every level of the hierarchy would need to keep a position of it's children in the event its children start looping through their children. It's been far too long, I'm not familiar with design-patterns & java's collections anymore.  :(

I'll note that I had an error when trying to use `Iterator< Hierarchical > itr = p.getChildren().iterator();` because p is of type Planet.

**Edit**: This needs to be "Depth-Last" (...or FIFO?). The looping is to simplify generation of the UI so the order is important.

Comment: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser.html

Comment: So you want an iterator that traverses the entire sub-hierarchy of a particular node? Do you want depth-first or breath-first?

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I don't think it is "first" or "last" but is instead "as encountered". I think Ramsay already posted a decent answer using recursion. I cant say I'm in-love with the result but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you right, you want to be able to visit every object in an object graph and do something with each object?

When each object implements a common interface, as yours do, this is simply resolved using recursion. Your only decision is whether you want to do depth-first recursion or breadth-first.

For depth first, you would want something like

```
public void visit(Hierarchical h) {
    // do something with h
    Iterator<Hierarchical> children = h.getChildren();
    while(children.hasNext()) {
        visit(children.next());
    }
}
```

> It would seem that every level of the hierarchy would need to keep a
>   position of it's children in the event its children start looping
>   through their children

Using recursion in this way, you don't need to keep track of any 'position' - the state of the iterator is kept on the stack as you call the method again, so as the stack unwinds, when you get to a 'seed', you will roll back up the stack a level and call the next iteration of the iterator.

For breadth-first, you will need to process an entire node first, collecting branches as you go. When you have finished processing all children you need to start on the collection of branches.

```
public void visit(Hierarchical h) {
    List<Hierarchical> branches = new LinkedList<>();
    Iterator<Hierarchical> children = h.getChildren();

    while(children.hasNext()) {
        Hierarchical h = children.next();
        // do something with h
        if(h.hasChildren()) {
            branches.add(h);
        }
    }

    for(Hierarchical branch : branches) {
        visit(branch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depth-first doesn't work for the UI. Apologies that I didn't explain, this is to iterate over multi-tiered variables to display on a grid. The order is important. (Added edit to original post.)

Comment: Yes, I see what you're doing now! With a little tweaking, this should work fine. I'll post my changes soon. Thank you.  =D